# Google Drive - Inserting Parent Folder for a file adds Root as a parent as well

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert api to update the parent folder for a particular file.

Example -

```
Original Folder - A
Dest Folder - B
Root Folder - /
File - a1
```

After submitting a post request to the above endpoint, 
we see the following in the parents section of the file.

parents : [
A, 
B, 
/
]

Is it a known issue ? How can I avoid it apart from having to delete the 'root' folder manually ?

Edit: Information about the apis used.

> Steps

1. Use - drive/v2/files/%s/permissions for Adding Permission
2. Use - drive/v2/files/%s/parents - for Inserting the parent. Set
    `"kind", "drive#parentReference" and "id", "destfolderId"` in the
    request

> Type of account - The folder being inserted into belongs to a 'Super
>   Admin'

Comment: Could you try and explain the problem a little more I don't understand.  The directory structure is back ward or what?

Answer (score 0):

Can't use comments due to reputation, but could you explain what you want to do a little bit more? Trying to move a file is more than just adding a new parent. Also check if root isn't already in the parent's array. Also you could use a query and list files to know what's going on more accurately. Use the built in list function in the developers page for faster access.

Links:

1. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
2. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters

Comment: I am essentially moving files between two users and I have authorization to do it on both of them's behalf. ( I have explicitly added 'Permission' for the file for the user). 

In order to move the file, I add the dest. user's folder as a parent and then, remove the current users' folder from the parent. 

However, using the insert REST request (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) adds 'ROOT' folder as a parent in addition to the 'dest. folder'. 

My question is why does the 'Root' get added even if I don't ask ?

Comment: What kind of account are you using to get this permission? You could also just make this other person the owner and the file will automatically appear in his folder, and just insert parent also so you could specify the /path/ where it should reside. I've done many folder and file operations, and I've never had a root automatically inserted in the parents array.

Comment: I have updated the question - with that information.

Comment: Well, for starters you have to first remove the parent, either the whole array or with the specific parent id (check list() in the API, with the parents parameter or even a query within Drive) and then add the new reference. I tried to do something similar but my folder ended up in nowhere with a faulty parent reference. Try to do the steps above, and tell me what happens.